# Filter data from TableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, firebase, uisearchbar

How can I filter a `tableView` by search bar? I fetch data to the `tableView` from a Firebase database and my search bar is inside `navigationBar`.

This is my code:

```
class TableViewCustomer: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var ref:DatabaseReference!
    var customerList = [CustomerModel]()
    lazy var searchBar: UISearchBar = UISearchBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 20))


    @IBOutlet weak var tableViewCustomer: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        searchBar.placeholder = "Search"
        navigationItem.titleView = searchBar

        if let textfield = searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField {
            textfield.textColor = UIColor.gray
            if let backgroundview = textfield.subviews.first {
                backgroundview.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
                backgroundview.layer.cornerRadius = 18
                backgroundview.clipsToBounds = true
            }
        }

        tableViewCustomer.delegate = self
        tableViewCustomer.dataSource = self

        ref = Database.database().reference().child("Customer");

        ref.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {
                self.customerList.removeAll()
                for results in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                    let results = results.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                    let name = results?["Name and surname"]
                    let phone = results?["Phone"]
                    let company = results?["Company name"]
                    let myCustomer = CustomerModel(name: name as? String, phone: phone as? String, company: company as? String)
                    self.customerList.append(myCustomer)
                }
                self.tableViewCustomer.reloadData()
            }
        })
    }

    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent
    }

    @objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return customerList.count
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableViewCustomer.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellCustomer") as! TableViewCellCustomer
        cell.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(white: 1, alpha: 0.7).cgColor
        let customer: CustomerModel
        customer = customerList[indexPath.row]
        cell.nameLabel.text = customer.name
        cell.phoneLabel.text = customer.phone
        cell.companyLabel.text = customer.company

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "description", sender: self)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your search bar, and an empty array. As you search add the suitable items to the empty array, then remove them from the array. Use the new array to index into your UI.

Comment: Here’s a decent example https://github.com/mrabins/EnsightenShopping/blob/master/shopping%20training%20app/ProductsViewController.swift

Comment: Thanks for comment!